# Git mv Files According to Regex Substitution

Tags: bash, git, xargs

I am trying to rename a large number of incorrectly named files, which are tracked in my local git repo. The files are currently of the form `foo.txt_1.txt`. And I want to change them to `foo.txt`.

This is what I have been experimenting with so far:

```
ls *_1.txt | xargs -I {} git mv -n {} newfilename
```

I'm just not sure what I should use in place if `newfilename` to make the substitution I want.

Comment: I updated my answer to be a little simpler (and does not execute sed for every line) thanks to feedback in the comments from Philippe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier with a for loop around it.

```sh
for f in *_1.txt; do
    echo git mv $f ${f/_1.txt/}
done
```

This will echo the commands it would run so you can check it's correct. Remove "echo" from before the "git" command to actually execute.

Bash inline substitution works like this:

```sh
${VAR/_1.txt/}
```

Where `VAR` is the variable name, and the pattern to remove is between the `/`s. Here it's simply text, but you can use regular expressions here.

Comment: What about `mv $f ${f/_1.txt/}` ?

Comment: I personally like to generate multiple commands (using exactly this sort of technique) but just save them into a file: `for f in ... done > /tmp/doit.sh`. Then I open the file in an editor, examine it for correctness, see if there's something easy to fix if it's not right, and then `sh /tmp/doit.sh` if it's right. Same general idea, but sometimes I just `ls *_1.txt > /tmp/doit.sh` and then edit that into the commands I want!

Comment: @Philippe wow... how did I not realize that... I've updated my answer to include that - thanks!