# Why Does Command Substitution Change Variable Value?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

Building off of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260954/git-mv-files-according-to-regex-substitution), I am trying to `git mv` a bunch of files using a string substitution. However, I neglected to mention that the file names contain whitespace, and that cannot be changed. So I put the substitution in double quotes to disable word splitting. This is what I have so far:

```
for file in *_1.txt
do
    git mv \"$file\" "$(echo $file | sed 's/_1.txt//')" 
done
```

The script gives me the following error:

```
fatal: destination 'texts/When Titans Drive.txt' is not a directory
```

All of the files are in a directory called `texts`, which also happens to be my working directory when I run the script. `When Titans Drive.txt` is one of the files.

I am not sure why the subshell is prepending the name of my working directory to `$file`. Why is this happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: You're getting that error from an `echo` command?

Comment: No I just made a mistake transcribing the script. I forgot to remove the echo I was using for testing.

Comment: Get rid of the backslashes before the quotes. That makes them literals instead of quoting the variable.

Comment: And put quotes around `$file` in `echo $file`

Comment: Looks like that took care of it.